# How to get index data from opensearch in Postman?

Tags: api, rest, get, postman, opensearch

I have built an opensearch index and I am trying to search the data it contains. I managed to view the details of the index in the dev tools, in http://localhost:5601/app/dev_tools#/console. I want to be able to query the opensearch through REST API using postman. As a request, I am using GET for the URL http://localhost:5601/my_index/_search and the request body looks like this (the type is raw, JSON):

```
   {
     "query": {
       "match": {
         "product": "1234"
       }
     }
   }
```

However, this results in the following error message:

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Not Found"
}
```

What am I missing when creating the GET request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port `5601` is for the OpenSearch Dashboard. OpenSearch by default runs at port `9200`. So try `http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search` instead.